# Applying a 2d convolution on a 2d Grid in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to do a 2d convolution, one a 2d grid, represented by a tensor of the following shape

```
[batch_dim, width, height]
```

Where the first dimensions is the 'batch dimension' an the second and third dimension represent the 2d grid

When I try to apply a 2d convolution using the following code:

```
nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
```

I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for  
4-dimensional weight 32 1 1 1, but got 3-dimensional
input of size [1, 132, 7] instead
```

Why does it a require 4d tensor for 2d grid with one channel? How should I implement a 2d convolution on a 2d grid?

Answer (score 0):

It should be in `batch size, channel, height, width` format, so yes 1 channel for a 2d grid. Using 1 channel won't change anything, don't implement it yourself, use the pytorch implementation.